# refresh html div ONLY ONCE without make very slow the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, refresh

i've this problem: with the click of a button, I run a php script thanks to ajax. But in the same time I want reload/refresh a html div in the same page. So when I do that with function such as: 7
`

```
setInterval(function() {
$("#IdDiv").load(location.href+" #IdDiv>*","");
}, 500);
```

`
the page run very slowly, mybe because the reload run in loop, I wish know the reason.
The refresh must will be in background.
Do you know solutions? Thanks

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting or monitoring at all? Checked the browser's console for potential issues?

Comment: what does it mean to refresh a div?

Comment: can you post all of your js and html please?

Comment: `setInterval` with lessthan a second! why not browser will get died because of loop in quick succession.

Comment: thanks for answers, this was an examples, how can i refresh it just once?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answers. it was an example, beacuse I don't want a interval but just only once. I need refresh it, in that div i run a mysql query that select same data(they are just changed in db when i pressed the button)

Comment: but same markup you are getting loaded why do you want it that way. `location.href` gives you the current page you are on and you are loading the `#IdDiv` content.

Comment: @Jai can you make an example?

Comment: @giovanniCiriello still your question is not clear, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: ok: with the button that i click I run in background a php script that insert data into my db. in the same time, into the div, I want show the data. So I need refresh it when I click the button

Comment: You could either send the new content for your div as the ajax response and populate the div with the ajax callback function, or separately refresh your div from within the callback.  You must not use setInterval, and setTimeout is not the best idea either.

Comment: Mh.. Can i see an example?

Comment: is `ONLY_ONCE` a constant?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you retrieve data from ajax calls. Send data to your php file with ajax, in php get data in form of object from db and then print or exit this object in json format:

file.php:

```
// some logic here
exit json_encode($dataFromDB);
```

$dataFromDB will be your ajax response object. Here's an example how to use it (with jQuery).

```
$.post("file.php", {data}, function(response) {
    // response object contains the data for you to append to webpage
    $("#myDiv").val(reponse.value);
}, "json");
```

BTW.
setInterval runs continuously, setTimeout will run only once.

Answer (score 0):

> The refresh must will be in background

It would appear `setInterval` is being used because it's thought that [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is synchronous - it isn't.

### $.load is *A* syncronous

With the following code:

```
$('<div/>').load('/', function() { console.log('second'); }); 
console.log('first');
```

The result is:

> first
>
> second

The code immediately after the load call is executed before the response from the server. Therefore to achieve updating a div in the background - *just* call it as normally:

```
$("#IdDiv").load(url);
```

### setInterval and setTimeout

Let's look at when to use `setInterval`, and `setTimeout` (since `setTimeout` is probably what was intended with the code in the question, and `setInterval` was used in error).

#### When to use setTimeout

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to do something once at a specific (though, approximate) time in the future:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // code to be executed exactly once, one second from now
}, 1000);
```

#### When to use setInterval

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to do something repeatedly in the future

```
now = new Date();
seconds = $('#seconds');

setInterval(function() {
    seconds.html(now.getSeconds());
}, 1000);
```

Be *extremely wary* of putting in a `setInterval` call anything of variable duration, or something which could under normal circumstances be delayed - otherwise there's the risk of the same symptoms as described in the question, whereby callbacks end up running in parallel, potentially crashing the browser.

#### When to use setTimeout as a pseudo interval

There's one scenario which fits inbetween the two methods `setTimout` and `setInterval`. When there is a need for something to be ran in a loop with a timer of inactivity *inbetween* successive calls.

Consider the following:

```
url = '/whatever';
function loopForever() {
    $("#IdDiv").load(url, function() {
        setTimeout(loopForever, 1000);
    });
}
```

This code will load the url and then one second from when it finishes - load it again (calling the named function again). Using `setTimeout` in this way avoids the problem of having callbacks executed in parallel as the next iteration is only scheduled to start when the last completes.